# Is the set of rational numbers $\mathbb Q$ dense in the irrationals?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I see the definition in wiki that $A$ is dense in $X$ iff every $x\in X$ is either in $A$ or a limit of $A$. So it does not require $A$ to be a subset of $X$?

And here is another theorem(or definition) in my book which says that $A$ is dense in $B$ if $A$ belongs to $B$ and $A$'s closure contains $B$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is implicitly assumed that $A$ is a subset of $X$. Otherwise, how can you say that an element of $X$ is a limit of elements of $A$?

Your argument passes to a larger space, the real numbers, and uses the fact that the rational numbers are dense there, to approximate the irrational numbers.

Comment: It seems perfectly reasonable to assert that $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $[0,1]$, even though $\Bbb Q\not\subseteq[0,1]$. How does "$x$ is a limit of elements of $A$" imply that $A\subseteq X$? (Of course, $A,X$ have to be subsets of a common topological space, but that's another matter.)

Comment: Mario, you are implicitly saying that $\Bbb Q\cap[0,1]$ is dense in $[0,1]$. Mathematicians make these sort of abuses of language all the time. To say that $x$ is a limit point (or adherence point, or whatever) of $A$ means that open neighborhood of $X$ meets $A$; then either you implicitly talk about $A\cap X$ or $A\cap X=\varnothing$ and your argument has become nonsense.

Comment: That's not quite right either, because $\Bbb Q$ is also dense in $\{\pi\}$ while $\Bbb Q\cap\{\pi\}=\emptyset$ is not.

Comment: Is it dense in $\{\pi\}$? Or is $\pi$ a limit point of $\Bbb Q$ in $\Bbb R$? The space $\{\pi\}$ is a singleton. What does it have to do with the rational numbers? I don't know.

Comment: My point is that "$A$ is dense in $X$ (in ambient top space $Y$)" has a meaning that is not necessarily preserved if you pass to a subspace as you are suggesting. From the quoted definition, it would seem that $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\{\pi\}$, since $\pi$ is a limit point of $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro You seem to be using a definition of "dense" that differs from the standard definition.  Perhaps you should clear things up by stating precisely what "$A$ is dense in $X$" means to you.

Comment: @Hayden I was attempting to use the definition from the OP. Checking the wiki reveals that it was mis-transcribed, and omitted the assumption $A\subseteq X$.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Great, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Mario: Either you decide to be accurate and you say that $\Bbb Q$ is dense as a subspace of $\Bbb Q\cup\{\pi\}$ in the relative topology induced from the standard topology of $\Bbb R$; or you are going to start making all sort of implicit assumptions, and rely on context - of which neither you (initially) nor the Wikipedia page  have provided, namely what are the sets and what is the ambient space. When you just say that $A$ is dense in $X$, you talk about the space $X$ with its topology and the set $A$. What you abuse and how is between you and your rabbi... Anyway, $\{\pi\}$ is a singleton.

Comment: @Mario: Not to mention that in case where there are several contexts in which you can interpret something, it seems reasonable to choose the one requiring least assumptions. Namely, that $A$ is a subset of $X$; and not the one talking about additional ambient spaces and whatnot. Yes, that's the price to pay when you are being inaccurate, and that's the price to pay when you learn something from Wikipedia and not from proper books.

Comment: @Asaf Note that I am already aware of the common definition of dense, which requires $A\subseteq X$; this discussion resulted from my usual approach of ignoring my own definitions in favor of the OP's when a definition is given. In any case, I think we are all on the same page now. Certainly under the usual definition, using a subspace topology, $\Bbb Q$ is not dense in $\{\pi\}$, nor is it dense in the irrationals.

Comment: @Mario: So you're saying that you just *really* wanted to argue with me on the internet? Gee, I'll keep that in mind for the future, since incidentally, I'm really trying to work right now (as this is my golden hour, 1 AM, although preferably slightly less sober than I am now).